# Is it possible to exchange the derivative sign with the integral sign in $\;\frac{d}{dy}(\int_0^\infty F(x)\frac{e^{-x/y}}{y}\,dx)\;$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I have to compute the following derivative

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\int_0^\infty F(x)\frac{e^{-x/y}}{y}\,dx\right)$$
where $F\colon\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$.

I would like to pass the derivative sign inside the improper integral in order to conclude that
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dy}\left(\int_0^\infty F(x)\frac{e^{-x/y}}{y}\,dx\right)=
\int_0^\infty F(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{e^{-x/y}}{y}\right)\,dx.
\end{align}
The problem is that the interval of the integral is not bounded so I cannot apply the classic theory. Do you know if there is any theorem that allows to switch the derivative and the integral sign when the interval of the integral is unbounded?

Thank you

Comment: What do you know about $F$?

Comment: I just know that it is a non-decreasing and positive function.

Answer (score 1):

For $ 0 \lt a \lt b \lt \infty$, you have for $y \in (a,b)$

$$\left\vert \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{y}}}{y}\right)  \right\vert \le A(a,b) e^{-\frac{x}{b}}$$ where $A(a,b)$ is a constant depending on $a,b$.

If $x \mapsto F(x) e^{-\frac{x}{b}}$ is integrable, you can use a corollary of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem to get the result you're looking for.